# Adding a reminder when creating a Calendar event using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a function to create a calendar event from a menu button in Google Sheets. The event gets created, however I am not able to set a custom reminder. It always sets it to "The day before at 11:50pm". I would like to be able to set the reminder to 4 weeks prior. Appreciate any guidance on how to add the reminder correctly?

Thanks!

Here is the code I am using:

```
function createCalEvent(eventSummary, eventLoc, eventDesc, eventDate) {
  console.log("> createCalEvent");
  const calendarId = 'primary';
  console.log(">> Summary: " + eventSummary);
  console.log(">> Location: " + eventLoc);
  console.log(">> Description: " + eventDesc);
  console.log(">> Date: " + eventDate);
  console.log(">> Calendar: " + calendarId);

  // event details for creating event.
  let event = {
    summary: eventSummary,
    location: eventLoc,
    description: eventDesc,
    start: {
      date: eventDate // must be in format "YYYY-MM-dd"
    },
    end: {
      date: eventDate
    },
    colorId: 11,  // Red background
    reminders: [
      { overrides: 40320 }.minutes // <- This does not seem to be working
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like this.

```html
colorId: 11,  // Red background
    reminders: {
      useDefault: false,
      overrides: [
        { method: 'popup', minutes: 40320 }
```